# Assume/switch role in aws toolkit for eclipse 2.0

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I am using aws toolkit for eclipse 2.0. using the options ( window -> preference -> aws toolkit) I have configured IAM/login user api access key id and secret access key. According to our aws configuration, this IAM user has to assume role to view/access any resources in our environment. I am doing it using aws cli with "–-profile " option. How to do the same thing in aws toolkit for eclipse ?

Comment: Did you get to know how to do it ? I want to switch to other account by assuming role ? No way to enter role arn in eclipse aws toolkit

Comment: Similar to this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892896/aws-toolkit-for-eclipse-2-0-iam-role-support

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out with help from an AWS expert.  Basically you do 2 things:

1. generate an AWS STS session token
2. use the "session token" values in your IDE.

Example:
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "value" --role-session-name "value" --duration-seconds "value"

put in the values generated for these in your eclipse IDE AWS profile:

```
    AccessKeyId
    SecretAccessKey
    SessionToken
```

You can also use a SAML assertion by using this command on the AWS CLI

```
aws sts assume-role-with-saml --role-arn "value" --principal-arn "value" --saml-assertion "value"
```

Note: the max session length is defined by the role you're using.

Answer (score -1):

In order to switch the account you will need to to add the below to your credentials file:

```
[regular]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxx

[dev]
source_profile = regular
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/RoleName
```

Once you do that, using AWS Toolkit, you can select "dev" profile and that's it!

Comment: This does not seem to work for me?  Anyone else get this to work?  I hae version 2.3.1 of the AWS Tookit for Eclipse Core and AWS lambda plugin v. 1.0.0 installed with Eclipse 2019-06 for windows